# barchart - count variable is showing frequency instead of values from data column

Tags: r, data-visualization, data-science, data-analysis

For reference, here is my data - 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZOKL.jpg)

I am trying to see a relationship between these variables and using barplot. Below is the R code I am using and plot I am getting.

```
library(lattice)
barchart(DiagAge~interaction(Gender,Race),groups=Ethnicity,data=df,auto.key=T,stack=T)
```

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4FMR.png)

I want to see DiagAge (an age when diabetes was diagnosed) on the Y-axis, however, the current code is showing some number that looks like frequency of something.

Comment: [This is a really handy site](http://r-statistics.co/Top50-Ggplot2-Visualizations-MasterList-R-Code.html), I'll see if I can post a solution at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `tidyr` and `ggplot` solution. I've used representative data to save time. In the future please add your data to your question using `dput(data)`. Here is a suggested solution: You can change the colours and themes as you wish.

```
   library(tidyverse)
df<-data.frame(Gender=c("M","F","M"),Race=c("Non White","White","Non White"),DiagAge=c(13,24,25))
df %>% 
  mutate_if(is.character,as.factor) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Race,DiagAge,fill=Gender))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="identity",col="black")+
  geom_label(aes(label=DiagAge))
```

Cheers

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I included my data with my original question,however, someone edited it.

Comment: Yes it did. I am getting a nice graph which has whites and non whites on x axis and age on y with two bar filled with gender. Looks great.

Comment: Also, I am wondering why are we using---   DiagAge=c(13,24,25) ?

Comment: It has no significance. Just like the `Race` column,I  have only used this as a representation.You can use whatever values you have in place of that(That is replace `df` with your data. It was simply for representation. Please feel free to accept this answer if and only if you feel it helped.

Answer (score 0):

`tidyverse` is your friend! Mainly, `ggplot2::geom_col`.

---

**Your code may look like this:**

```
library(tidyverse)

mytbl <- df %>%
  mutate(racegender = paste(Race,Gender)) 

g <- ggplot(mytbl, aes(racegender)) + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Spectral")

g + geom_col(aes(fill = Ethnicity, y = DiagAge)) +
  labs(title="Your title", 
       subtitle="Your subtitle") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=65, vjust=0.6))
```

---

**Here I use this code on the `diamonds` dataset to illustrate your situation.**

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Create a `cutcolor` variable via `mutate`. I `filter` for certain values for the sake of brevity in my example (not necessary or valid for you, most likely).

```
mytbl <- diamonds %>%
  mutate(cutcolor = paste(cut,color)) %>% 
  filter(color %in% c("D", "E", "F"),
         cut %in% c("Fair", "Good", "Very Good"))  # to limit the number of columns
```

The graph will use `mytbl` and have `cutcolor` on the horizontal axis:

```
g <- ggplot(mytbl, aes(cutcolor)) + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Spectral")
```

The primary `ggplot` function is `geom_col`. `fill` stacks 'em, and the vertical axis is `price` (`DiagAge` in your case). The `theme` part helps to angle to horizontal label text.

```
g + geom_col(aes(fill = clarity, y = price)) +
  labs(title="Bar Graph with Stacked Types", 
       subtitle="Price Across Diamond Cut and Color") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=65, vjust=0.6))angle=65, vjust=0.6))
```

Result:

[image: Cut/Color with Stacked Clarity vs. Price]

Comment: this is a really good representation. Thank you for explaining it to me as well. Its makes more sense to me now.